# Turn off emoticons in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios

I'd like to be able to stop iOS automatically converting emoticons as pictures. I want it so that, for example, instead of a picture of a smiling face my phone displays the raw characters of a colon followed by a right bracket [ :) ].

Anyone have any more thoughts on this?

Comment: Could you clarify what version of iOS you're running?

Comment: 10.3.1 on both iPhone and iPad

Comment: It happens on multiple different apps - Mail, Messages, Safari, Chrome.

Comment: Are you certain that what is being sent is not actually an emoji? Neither my Mac nor iPhone auto-translate :) nor anything else, to an emoji. iOS will offer a replacement, but if you don't accept it, it will not send one.

Comment: Yes I'm certain it is an emoticon

Answer (score 1):

It's a feature of iOS 10. You'll have to delete the emoji keyboard to get rid of that, by going to Settings > General > Keyboards.

Since iOS 10 introduced the predictive text feature, you can type in English and have words corrected in other languages, provided that the keyboard is enabled.

Comment: I don't have the emoticon keyboard enabled. I still see them converted to pictures regardless of whether the keyboard is enabled or not.

Comment: Nonsense, the keyboard has nothing to do with this.

Comment: I didn't say the keyboard was responsible, I was replying to someone who suggested that it might be.

Comment: @user29742 my comment, like your first one, is addressed to the person posting the "answer"

Comment: Ah,  my apologies.